# Django run external py script on html click

Tags: python, html, django

since im beginner to Django framework and python language. I need help. I need to run external python script from html button also to get value from html and show the output back to web page.

Example workflow:

```
Input text : "hello", click "submit" on html button. 

Run world.py : receive "hello" as variable. Add "world" 

Post it back to the same html page and shows  "helloworld" .
```

How to :

1.run the external.py a d send the value

2. On py files, receive value, process it, then return value to html page:

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find an [example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/#building-a-form-in-django) of how to do what you need.

Anyway, I the rationale is

- Create a view which returns a simple page with a Form (with the input text) upon a GET request
- Carry out a POST request to the same view upon form submission (with the "submit" button)
- Then, in the POST request handle of the view, run the script you need (by importing it or if you really need to run it as an "external" script, which is quite unusual, you can use Python [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html)) and return the output of the script as the return value of the POST handle

Comment: Oh, so the usual way is by importing the script, and use POST to send value from html?

Comment: Exactly, a simple POST with a form is the easiest way you can send data to the back-end (note that using Django forms is not mandatory, but is more convenient to handle the data), and if the script you want to run is a Python script, the best way to run it is by importing the functionalities you need from the script and use them (be it a method, a class, you name it)